# Get current value of a double animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a story board where I am making a rectangle move up like a needle in a MPH car gauge. So, I make it go from 0 to 60 and I want to be able to get its current value while it's changing so I can use that value to make a digital gauge.

How can I get the current value from the beginning to the end of a double animation? I have something like this:

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
da.From = 0;
da.To = 60;
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
rt.CenterX = 35;
rt.CenterY = 0;
rec3.RenderTransform = rt;
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
```

When it rotates the rectangle up I tried to get that angle but it just returned zero.

Comment: I think it would help, if you showed how exactly you are going to use changed Angle value. H.B. showed how to bind UI element to the changing Angle, I showed how to get the angle at any moment programmatically. If none of those answers work for you, you need to add more details to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong, consider this example:

```xml
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="10" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rt" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=rt, Path=Angle}" />
```

```cs
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, new DoubleAnimation(0, 60, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), FillBehavior.HoldEnd));
```

It displays the value just fine.

---

If you assign the `rt.Angle` to some variable that variable will have the value of the transform angle at that point in time, it will **not change** concurrently with the `rt.Angle` property.

If you are new to databinding which i used in the above code you might want to check out the [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: is there a way t get that value in the code behind without binding? doesnt sound like it

Comment: What would be the point? If you have some piece of code you still can only access the current value at the time that piece of code is executed, what would you want to do? Of course you can create a dedicated property and animate that only to then bind both the transform and the digital display to that property.

Comment: I was just hoping i could do segments like a 7 segment display. i want to switch from analog to digital

Comment: well i am simulating a car gauge. It has a rectangle for a needle that i am making it go up according to the story board. It works great. However, i also want to be able to switch to digital to display  the RPM that way like in a 7 segments like a digital clock. so i need to get the value so i can run a  switch on it.

Comment: Then you should have a speed property in your model and the displays should represent that value in different ways.

Comment: I did this recently with an analog clock and made  a digital clock but it was based off of time and was easy to do the segments.

Comment: im not sure how to do a speed property - so theres no way to do it from the animation then?

Comment: Well, just some property, probably of type int which you can animate (not necessarily with the built-in animations). If it's not a DependencyProperty the model should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so you can bind to it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how you would turn the speed into segments but you can do a binding with a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to turn your speed into something else.

Comment: i know what your saying with INotifyPropertyChanged i did that with the time. I got the current time and split it inot 2 variables and used a switch to toggle visibility on the segments. I was hoping to do the same thing with the current value of the animation.

Comment: I cant chnage the direction i went in with the storyboard to power the analog car MPH gauge so i cant do segments for the digital then

Comment: If you cannot change that you are now successfully stuck with a bad design.

Comment: i was told i could  set a x:Name on the RotateTransform and get that value directly.<RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" /> and double to = (rotateLeft.Children[0] as DoubleAnimation).To;  but theres no rotateleft i think this is in silverlight

Comment: i guess i can try to get the angle of the rectangle as it rotating in the code behind

Comment: You can get the angle from the transform, at worst you need to cast the RenderTransform.

Comment: how can i get the angle from  the transform? rt?

Comment: `rt.Angle` or if you have no direct reference `(rect.RenderTransform as RotateTransform).Angle`.

Comment: thank you i got the angle value. dont know if i can use it or not but thanks for everything. i will probobly end up just binding to a textbox

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly is the problem you are facing, but I just checked and this code will show you the current Angle:

```
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
    da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    da.From = 0;
    da.To = 60;
    rt.CenterX = 35;
    rt.CenterY = 0;
    rectangle1.RenderTransform = rt;
    rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = rt.Angle; // x will have the value of current angle
}
```

**[Edit]**

If you need to access private rt.Angle from another class you could expose it via property like:

```
public Double CurrentAngle
{
    get { return rt.Angle; }
}
```

Comment: how can i keep getting the current value without having to click a  button? If i add that var x = rt.Angle; to the bottom of the animation it just returns zero.

Comment: I have checkboxes to simulate gears so the above code is in a private void checkBox2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) how can i keep getting its current value because it just returns zero

Comment: @icelated - not sure I understand. If you need a textbox continuously updated with new Angle, use binding like H.B. showed. If you need to access it programmaticaly, just access Angle property when you need it.

Comment: for some reason its still returning zero

Comment: @Alex Aza: I think icelated thought that `x = rt.Angle` would make x reference the angle. Of course that is not the case and right after the animation start code the angle is still 0 (and x will always be 0 after that assignment)

Comment: exactly hb - How can i get the current value then? i need to do it in the code behind if possible

Comment: @icelated - if it is private, you can expose it via property. I showed this in my answer.

Comment: @icelated: In answers which are not the person's who you are addressing your comment needs to start with @<Name> or the person you are taling to will not be notified; just so you know, since i did not get that message (not that it matters here since Alex could answer that as well)

Comment: @icelated I'm having the same problem here (silverlight). did you solved it eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Despite some posters here claiming otherwise, I also noticed that it is difficult to access the current value of an animated property while the animation is in progress. Here is a nice solution I have used to make use of WPF animations to interpolate values over time in my model.

```
public class AnimatedDoubleValue : UIElement
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void FirePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private double _value_cache; // this stores the current animated value!
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            if (_value_cache == value)
                return;
            _value_cache = value;
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            FirePropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(AnimatedDoubleValue), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, ValuePropertyChanged));

    private static void ValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = (AnimatedDoubleValue)sender;
        var value = (double)e.NewValue;
        self.UpdateValue(value);
    }

    private void UpdateValue(double value)
    {
        _value_cache = value;
        FirePropertyChanged("Value");
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, the OP wanted to reuse WPFs animation tools for his simulation. This is not a bad idea, since interpolating values according to elapsed time is not exactly trivial.

This AnimatedDoubleValue doesn't even have to be linked into the WPF widget tree. It can be just used to get updates of an animated value. Use like this:

```
var doubleValue = new AnimatedDoubleValue();
var animation=new DoubleAnimation() { From=0, To=100, Duration=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
animation.SetValue(Storyboard.DesiredFrameRateProperty, 30);
doubleValue.BeginAnimation(AnimatedDoubleValue.ValueProperty, animation, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
```

Now either listen to PropertyChanged event on doubleValue or access its Value property any time you wish.

Comment: Don't know why this was voted down.. after 3 days of searching this is a great starting point for an animation class to get the values of animations

Comment: This is the correct solution to catch the animation value out of a calculated animation. By using `OldValue` its possible to calculate the fraction / power.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening. I had a similar problem but with getting position of an element during animation of its movement. I solved it in my case by using time. This approach is based on knowing the elapsed time after animation started. Let say, we have that piece of element's class code:

```
Location = new Point(100, 100);

// set animations
var moveTime = 5000.0;
var function = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
var shift = new Point(1000, 700);
var locationAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation
{
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(moveTime),
    To = shift .X,
    EasingFunction = function
};
var locationAnimationY = new DoubleAnimation
{
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(moveTime),
    To = shift .Y,
    EasingFunction = function
};

// attach animations to this element and its properties
Storyboard.SetTarget(locationAnimationX, this);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(locationAnimationX, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)");
Storyboard.SetTarget(locationAnimationY, this);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(locationAnimationY, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");

// create storyboard and start animation of move
var moveStory = new Storyboard();
moveStory.Children.Add(locationAnimationX);
moveStory.Children.Add(locationAnimationY);
moveStory.Begin();
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
```

For example, we have to know current location after some time. So let's start.

```
var elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;  
var ratio = elapsedTime / moveTime;
var funcCurrentValue = function.Ease(ratio);
var currentShift = new Point(shift.X * funcCurrentValue, shift.Y * funcCurrentValue);
```

Finally, current location is given by:

```
var currentLocation = new Point(Location.X + currentShift.X, Location.Y + currentShift.Y);
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I did not write at start but this is an answer of course. Thanks for the advice and sorry for mess.